# Automatic "go back" to previous url

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get redirect to the previous URL I was on.

I used this     `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=javascript:history.back();">`but it doesnt work it gives me this error:

```
redirectrequireditems.html:14 Refused to refresh http://localhost/Test.com/redirectrequireditems.html to a javascript: URL
```

Line 14 is     `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=javascript:history.back();">`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you just adding `<script>window.history.back();</script>` to your page for example?

Comment: Sure seems like an unfriendly user experience. Why would you ever need to do this on such a short interval? Might be cleaner ways for user to do what you want...whatever that is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if we can do it through META tag, I have the following solution using JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout("window.history.go(-1)",2000);
</script>
```